# Flatten a list of lists of tuples

Tags: python

I have read several posts on the question "how to flatten lists of lists of lists ....". And I came up with this solution:

```
points = [[[(6,3)],[]],[[],[]]] 
from itertools import chain
list(chain.from_iterable(points))
```

However my list looks sometimes like this:

```
[[[(6,3)],[]],[[],[]]]
```

Not sure if it is correct but I hope you understand.

The point is the leaf element is a tuple and when calling the above code it also removes the tuple and just returns `[6,3]`.

So what could i do to just get `[(6,3)]` ?

Comment: you can get the result like this: `[tuple([6,3])]`

Comment: Did you try this solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/40547477/1904113 ? As it only flattens lists, this should work for you.

Comment: whenever you are posting a question better you provide the input and output also. Thanks

Comment: As you can see i provided the input list and my output....?

Comment: @MKesper your answer works like a charm

Comment: I just tried your code and got back [[(6, 3)], [], [], []], and not [6,3] as you describe...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe its not the best solution, but it works fine:

```
def flat(array):
    result = []
    for i in range(len(array)):
        if type(array[i]) == list:
            for j in flat(array[i]):
                result.append(j)
        else:
            result.append(array[i])
    return result     

print flat([[[(6,3)],[]],[[],[]]] )
```

and the result is:

```
>>> 
[(6, 3)]
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this,

```
lists = [[[(6,3)],[]],[[],[]]] 

r = [t for sublist in lists for l in sublist for t in l]

print(r)
# [(6, 3)]
```